I am getting solana-test-validator error while creating test-ledger
When I try to run that command, it gives me that error and I haven't fix yet. Is there anyone who gets that error before and solve


Did you try running it in another folder? Maybe you dont have write access where you currently are? Or try reinstall solana cli.
